# Hibernate - how to use a list of integers?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity with a field of type `List<Integer>`, and I'm having trouble saving and loading it with hibernate.

I found out about @ElementCollection (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050507/mapping-a-list-of-integer-with-hibernate)), but I can't get it to work.

Here's my entity:

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Integer> integers;

    public TestEntity() {

    }

    public TestEntity(String id, List<Integer> integers) {
        this.id = id;
        this.integers = integers;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Integer> getIntegers() {
        return integers;
    }
}
```

And here's my main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory()) {
            try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
                TestEntity entity = new TestEntity("id", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
                session.persist(entity);
            }

            try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
                TestEntity entity = (TestEntity) session.byId(TestEntity.class.getName()).load("id");
                System.out.println(entity.getIntegers().size());
            }
        }
    }

    private static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure()
                .build();

        return new MetadataSources(registry)
                .addAnnotatedClass(TestEntity.class)
                .buildMetadata()
                .buildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

This code fails with NullPointerException because the integers list is null. What am I missing?

Comment: Post log error please.

Comment: As you passing "id" in test entity, it is looking for an object with that id. Can you try removing that.

Comment: Did you check if not the entity itself is null? I'm not sure what default ID generator is used when you are not specifying one. When it is anything different to "assigned", you cannot just assign your own value.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Integer> integers;
public void setIntegers(List<Integer> integers) {
         this.integers = integers; }
```

Using a setter method would help

- You are getting a *NullPointerException* as the list is null
- This would be solved by the use of setters

Comment: Not so sure. It's using field access, therefore should require a setter.

Comment: I added a setter, and I'm still getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: Then you need to check step by step using SOP

Comment: What do you mean by SOP?

Comment: Using System.out.println(); and commenting portion of your code step by step you might find the error!

Comment: Turns out I forgot to start a transaction, so the entire entity was null, rather than just the list. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I forgot to open a transaction when writing the TestEntity :(

Now the code works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (SessionFactory sessionFactory = createSessionFactory()) {
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            TestEntity entity = new TestEntity("id", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
            session.persist(entity);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            TestEntity entity = session.get(TestEntity.class, "id");
            System.out.println(entity.getIntegers().size());
        }
    }
}
```